# USB boot с .bin и образом floppy диска в .img

Tags: virtualbox, ос, boot, live-usb, qemu

*Проходя мимо поднимайте тему выше, потому что решить вопрос не могу давно, нужны мысли специалистов.*

**Ситуация такая :**

Есть .img образ floppy-диска

Если его встроить вот сюда в **VirtualBox** :[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То при запуске всё успешно отработает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если его запускать через Qemu :

```
 qemu.exe  -m 32 -boot a -fda BOOT_FLP.IMG
```

То также всё успешно отработает

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно повторить тоже самое на реальной машине.

Проблема разворота на реальной машине в том, что он пишет "ALeeee" в любом случае.

Если запускать через Qemu на прямую, без параметров с батником, то выдаст "ALeeee".

У кого есть идеи и мысли?

Перепробовал тонну программ от Win32DiskImage до RMPrepUSB... Ну очень много вариантов перепробовал.

Кому интересно также подключайтесь к обсуждению или поднимайте тему.

**Для тех, кто хочет блеснуть умом, говорю сразу :**

Есть и bootloader.bin для floppy-диска от архитектур x86 и x64.

Может я делаю что-то не так?

С другими .img ,например с образом старого ms-dos, это работает. А в данной ситуцаии нет. Я думал по началу, что это косяк моего .img, но qemu и virtualbox читают его и работают с ним.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте ImageUSB by PassMark Software[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: сейчас посмотрю

Comment: бесполезно, та же история с "ALeee" он просто не хочет подгружать это